# How can I do an inner join of two collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
// orders collection
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "orderName": "a",
    "seqId": 100,
    "etc": [],
    "desc": [],
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "orderName": "b",
    "seqId": 200,
    "etc": [],
    "desc": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "orderName": "c",
    "seqId": 100,
    "etc": [],
    "desc": [],
  },
]
```

```
// goods collection
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "example1",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "details": [
          {
            "id": 100
          },
          {
            "id": 101,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 20,
        "details": [
          {
            "id": 102,
          },
          {
            "id": 103,
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "example2",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 30,
        "details": [
          {
            "id": 200
          },
          {
            "id": 201
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 40,
        "details": [
          {
            "id": 202
          },
          {
            "id": 203
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

When the value of the seqId field of the document whose etc field and desc field arrays of the orders collection are empty and the value of the "goods.details.id field of the goods collection are the same, I want to get the following output. How can I do that?

```
[
  {orderName: "a", title: "example1"},
  {orderName: "b", title: "example2"},
  {orderName: "c", title: "example1"},
]
```

Additionally, I would like to perform a sum operation based on the title of the goods
collection.

```
[
  {"example1": 2}, 
  {"example2": 1}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply perform a `$lookup` between `orders.seqId` and `goods.items.details.id`. Use `$unwind` to eliminate empty lookups(i.e. inner join behaviour). Finally, do a `$group` with `$sum` to get the count.

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "etc": [],
      "desc": []
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "goods",
      "localField": "seqId",
      "foreignField": "items.details.id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            title: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "goodsLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$goodsLookup"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$goodsLookup.title",
      cnt: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y1JI3L9pEdy)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran the above query with mongosh but I get the following error. "MongoServerError: $lookup with 'pipeline' may not specify 'localField' or 'foreignField'"

Comment: @newbieeyo What is your MongoDB version? If you are using a version prior to v5.0, this [concise syntax](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-a-concise-correlated-subquery-with--lookup) may not be available to you. However for your case, it may not actually be necessary since it is just a `$project` for performance. You can try to completely remove the pipeline in the `$lookup` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DHukN6NF18I) to see if you can achieve the same result.

Comment: can i ask one more? What if I want to sum by title even if the etc and desc arrays are not empty? For example, I want it to output something like {example1: 1, total: 2}.

Comment: @newbieeyo Do you mean removing the `$match` at the start like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6KTqFb4LW3K)?

Comment: yes but, the result when there is $match and the result when there is no match should be output together. For example, if {example: 1, total:2}, the total number of example means when there is $match and there is no total

Comment: @newbieeyo sorry but it starts to become too long to fit in comments here. Would you please ask a new question and link back to this question to provide some context(and also your new scenario)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75435704/how-to-do-mongodb-inner-join-and-grouping